# how to get multiple folder path on the azure logic app

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a scenario : I want to build an azure logic app, where I have to got documents from various folder from the Sharepoint get process and give email notification. My confusion is how can I give multiple input folder path?

Comment: You can add multiple connectors but Can we know what is your requirement?

Comment: My requirement is extracting an acronym from various file like excel, DOCX, PDF and save as a CSV, and all the file is different Sharepoint location. My scrip has to get all the SharePoint folder path. i want to make a logic app  in such a way where i can give a all the input folder path and get process ave the outcome.

Comment: are you trying to extract the whole content from excel, docs or Pdf files to CSV?

Comment: Same SharePoint tenant but different sites?  Or same SharePoint tenant and same site, just different folders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumptions with your architecture in my answer.  I'm assuming you want to process multiple files in different sites within the same SharePoint tenant.  So, not across tenants.

To achieve what you're asking for, I created a `Parse JSON` action which takes in the following structure (as an example, obviously the structure is the key point here, not the data) ...

## Scenario 1 - Specific Files

```
[
  {
    "SiteName": "ExampleSolution",
    "FileName": "/Shared Documents/General/Book.xlsx"
  },
  {
    "SiteName": "TestSite",
    "FileName": "/Shared Documents/Test Folder/Document.docx"
  }
]
```

The SP tenant needs to be authenticated to with the appropriate user.

Then, in a `For Each` action, loop through each item and retrieve the contents of each document using the `Get file content using path` action.

[image: For Each]

**Site Address** = `concat('https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/', items('For_each')?['SiteName'])`

**File Path** = `File Name` (from *Dynamic Content*)

It will then retrieve the contents dynamically using those expressions.

#### File 1 (Excel Document)

[image: File 1]

#### File 2 (Word Document)

[image: File 2]

## Scenario 2 - All Files

If you want to do it for all files, just change it up slightly ...

```
[
  {
    "FolderName": "/Shared Documents/General",
    "SiteName": "ExampleSolution"
  },
  {
    "FolderName": "/Shared Documents/Test Folder",
    "SiteName": "TestSite"
  }
]
```

[image: For Each 2]

**Site Address** = `concat('https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/', items('For_each')?['SiteName'])`

**File Identifier** = `Folder Name` (from *Dynamic Content*)

#### Output - Folder 1

```
[
  {
    "Id": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fGeneral%252fBook.xlsx",
    "Name": "Book.xlsx",
    "DisplayName": "Book.xlsx",
    "Path": "/Shared Documents/General/Book.xlsx",
    "LastModified": "2021-12-24T02:56:14Z",
    "Size": 15330,
    "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "IsFolder": false,
    "ETag": "\"{23948609-0DA0-43E0-994C-2703FEEC8567},7\"",
    "FileLocator": "dataset=aHR0cHM6Ly9icmFka2RpeG9uLnNoYXJlcG9pbnQuY29tL3NpdGVzL0V4YW1wbGVTb2x1dGlvbg==,id=JTI1MmZTaGFyZWQlMmJEb2N1bWVudHMlMjUyZkdlbmVyYWwlMjUyZkJvb2sueGxzeA==",
    "LastModifiedBy": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fGeneral%252fTest%2bDocument.docx",
    "Name": "Test Document.docx",
    "DisplayName": "Test Document.docx",
    "Path": "/Shared Documents/General/Test Document.docx",
    "LastModified": "2021-12-30T11:49:28Z",
    "Size": 17959,
    "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "IsFolder": false,
    "ETag": "\"{7A3C7133-02FC-4A63-9A58-E11A815AB351},8\"",
    "FileLocator": "dataset=aHR0cHM6Ly9icmFka2RpeG9u etc",
    "LastModifiedBy": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fGeneral%252fHierarchy.xlsx",
    "Name": "Hierarchy.xlsx",
    "DisplayName": "Hierarchy.xlsx",
    "Path": "/Shared Documents/General/Hierarchy.xlsx",
    "LastModified": "2022-01-07T02:49:38Z",
    "Size": 41719,
    "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "IsFolder": false,
    "ETag": "\"{C919454C-48AB-4897-AD8C-E3F873B52E50},72\"",
    "FileLocator": "dataset=aHR0cHM6Ly9icmFka2RpeG9uL etc",
    "LastModifiedBy": null
  }
]
```

#### Output - Folder 2

```
[
  {
    "Id": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fTest%2bFolder%252fTest.xlsx",
    "Name": "Test.xlsx",
    "DisplayName": "Test.xlsx",
    "Path": "/Shared Documents/Test Folder/Test.xlsx",
    "LastModified": "2022-01-09T11:08:31Z",
    "Size": 17014,
    "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "IsFolder": false,
    "ETag": "\"{CCF71CE7-89E7-4F89-B5CB-0F078E22C951},163\"",
    "FileLocator": "dataset=aHR0cHM6Ly9icmFka2RpeG9u etc",
    "LastModifiedBy": null
  },
  {
    "Id": "%252fShared%2bDocuments%252fTest%2bFolder%252fDocument.docx",
    "Name": "Document.docx",
    "DisplayName": "Document.docx",
    "Path": "/Shared Documents/Test Folder/Document.docx",
    "LastModified": "2022-01-09T11:08:16Z",
    "Size": 17293,
    "MediaType": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
    "IsFolder": false,
    "ETag": "\"{317C5767-04EC-4264-A58B-27A3FA8E4DF3},3\"",
    "FileLocator": "dataset=aHR0cHM6Ly9icmFka2RpeG etc",
    "LastModifiedBy": null
  }
]
```

From here, just process each file individually using one of the files actions like in the first scenario above.

**Note:** *You'll need to work through sub folders and recursion.  There doesn't appear to be a way to do that easily.*

You've provided very little information but it should be enough for you to adapt it accordingly.

Also, I strongly recommend you use a means other than a hardcoded JSON document in the action itself.  There are way better means for housing that information which wouldn't result in a need to update the action itself everytime you want to add or delete a file.

The concept of the loop and and the expressions are the most important part to grasp as they will give you what you want.